# How to modify mariadb chartset at once?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, emoji, utf8mb4

I am developing with mariadb and Spring, JdbcTemplate.

At first, we made DB charset as `utf8`, but now we have to change it into `utf8mb4` because of emojis.

Till now I update individual charset with query something like below.

```
ALTER TABLE WT_WORKS CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE WT_WORKS CHANGE WORKS_TITLE WORKS_TITLE VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE WT_WORKS CHANGE WORKS_DESC WORKS_DESC VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However It is now efficient because of table relations. For example when I insert into `WT_WORKS`, also need to into `WT_WRITERS`. It looks impossible to find every tables and columns.

So I want to know change these at once.(Including `Procedures` and `Functions`). -- something like `(v_name VARCHAR(10))` into `(v_name VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8mb4)`.

Thanks for answer.

FYI. my `my.cnf` got follow settings

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    FROM  information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE  CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8'
```

will list all the tables that still have some column set to utf8.  When them, do `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;`

This should generate all the `ALTERs` you need:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            "ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME,
            "  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;"
              )
    FROM  information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE  CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8'
```

Then copy and paste them into the mysql command line tool.

Caveat:  If you have some columns with charsets other than utf8, they will be blindly converted to utf8mb4.  This would be bad for hex, ascii, etc., columns, such as `country_code`, `uuid`, `md5`, etc.

You could do something similar to change individual columns instead.

You do not need to do both.

Comment: It looks like can not fix with just one query. Thanks though.

Comment: True.  One query would generate a list of many `ALTERs`, which would then need to be run.